# Identifying Bold Text in PDF using pyPdf

Tags: python, pypdf

I am using `pyPdf` to extract text from a PDF. I would like to be able to know which text is bold in order to identify bold section headers. How can I identify bold text?

Answer (score 0):

pypdf has no direct support for it - it's not impossible, but it would require significant effort from your side. As pypdf is no longer maintained, this will not change.

PyPDF2 also does not have this at the moment (May 2022), but I'm open to a PR adding this support.